# How can you reduce the 'current' time in setTimeOut?

Tags: javascript

How can you reduce the 'current' time in setTimeOut? For example I have a countdown going from 100s, after 40s (so at 60s) I click a button and it instantly reduces to 50s (-10s).

The link in the example below enables after 100 seconds. Basically I'm looking for a way to reduce 10 seconds from the (current position in the) countdown every time a button is pressed.

```
function enableLink() {
    setTimeout('enableAnchor( "anchor0", "mylink.php" )', 100000);
}
```

If this isn't possible, is there any language or library (JQuery or AJAX perhaps?) that would allow me to do this?

Comment: You can't do this (jQuery or no jQuery). You'll have to cancel the timeout, and set-up another one to execute sooner.

Comment: You understand that jQuery is a library, not a language, and AJAX is neither, right? Also, don't pass strings to `setTimeout`; it's `eval` in disguise. Pass functions instead.

Comment: As Matt said, you'd have to cancel the timeout and set up another one, but if this is something you'll need to do a lot, you *could* (and I'm not saying this is a good idea for your use, just that it *may* be) make your own object to mimic cron where you register functions against a time (which you could then change whenever) and have a function that checks for any queued executions every second or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the timer values for any real logic, do it by hand:

```
var msLeft = 100000,
    prev = new Date();

     //This timer is simply polling how much time has passed using accurate methods and reduces it accordingly from msLeft 
var timerId = window.setInterval( function() {
    var cur = new Date(),
        progress = cur - prev;

    prev = cur;
    msLeft -= progress;

    if( msLeft <= 0 ) {
        window.clearInterval(timerId);
        counteddown();
    }
}, 50 ); 

document.onclick = function() {
    msLeft -= 10000; //Each click reduces 10 seconds from the countdown
};

document.onkeyup = function() {
    msLeft += 10000; //Each keyup adds 10 seconds to the countdown
};
```

jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/JgzZQ/2/

Comment: Why `+new Date` and not `new Date` ?

Comment: @Mageek it turns the date into a number of ms since epoch. It's actually useless here since `cur - prev` would convert it anyway

Answer (score 2):

One way you could achieve this is with a method which looks much like setTimeout, but returns an object with a method which allows you to reduce the time. This negates the need to keep polling to see whether the time has been reduced, only re-allocating the timer when necessary:

```
function adjustableTimer(action, initialMs){   
    return {
        timerId: setTimeout(action, initialMs),
        startTime: new Date(),
        initialMs: initialMs,
        action: action,
        reduce: function(howMuch){
            var elapsedTime = new Date() - this.startTime;
            var remainingTime = this.initialMs - elapsedTime;
            var newTime = remainingTime - howMuch;
            clearTimeout(this.timerId);            
            this.timerId = setTimeout(this.action,newTime);
        }
    };       
}
```

Usage:

```
var timer = adjustableTimer(function(){ alert("Im finished"); }, 10000); // initially 10 seconds
// when wanting to reduce:
timer.reduce(1000); // reduce timer by 1 second
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gKjEt/